# Android YouTube API - Handling Orientation Change with No Buffering

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, buffer, android-youtube-api

I am using Android YouTube API to show a video in portrait mode. Upon playing the video and turning the device into landscape mode, the video continues from the spot left off but re-buffers. I am looking for a solution as to how avoid the re-buffering.

I know for a fact its possible since Google provides an example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), and it works flawlessly except I can't seem to make it work with my application. I am unsure as to which functions to override and which ones actually remove the re-buffering.

Edit: here's the full xml for the cell in the ListView; the YouTubePlayerView is added programmatically after the last TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_shape"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_username_tv"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_when_tv"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="top|right"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_content_tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="17dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know within java you'd need to override "onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)" and perhaps also "onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen)", but just how exactly do you "grow" the youtube view without rebuffering? I tried using code from the full screen sample but it didn't seem to work out for me. Here is the player itself:

```
public class YouTubeParser extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener, YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private String youtubeUrl;
    private com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView youtube;
    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private Context mContext;
    private boolean fullscreen;

    private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
            ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
                    : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

    public YouTubeParser(View v, Context context, Post post, String lastUrl) {
        this.mContext = context;
        youtubeUrl = post.getYoutubeUrl();
        TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_username_tv);
        TextView when = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_when_tv);
        TextView content = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_content_tv);


        if (username != null)
            username.setText(post.getUsername());
        if (when != null)
            when.setText(post.getWhen());
        if (content != null) {
            content.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getContent()));
            content.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        if (lastUrl != youtubeUrl) {
            youtube = new com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView(context);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            youtube.setLayoutParams(params);

            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.youtube_ll);
            if (ll.getChildCount() == 4)
                ll.removeViewAt(2);
            ll.addView(youtube, 2);
        }
        if (youtube != null) {
            youtube.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(getString(0), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        this.player = player;
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(this);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(youtubeUrl);
            Log.i("Position", "video cued: " + youtubeUrl);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youtube;
    }

    public void setNoLandscape() {
        if (player != null) {
            int controlFlags = player.getFullscreenControlFlags();
            controlFlags &= ~YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
            player.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
            if (mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                player.pause();
        }
    }

    public void setToLandscape() {
        if (player != null) {
            int controlFlags = player.getFullscreenControlFlags();
            controlFlags |= YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
            player.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {
        setNoLandscape();
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {
        int controlFlags = player.getFullscreenControlFlags();
        controlFlags |= YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
        player.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        fullscreen = isFullscreen;
        doLayout();

    }

    private void doLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams playerParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) youtube.getLayoutParams();
        if (fullscreen) {
            // When in fullscreen, the visibility of all other views than the player should be set to
            // GONE and the player should be laid out across the whole screen.
            playerParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            playerParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        } else {
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                playerParams.width = 0;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                playerParams.weight = 1;
            } else {
                playerParams.width = MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                playerParams.weight = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        doLayout();
    }


}
```

Comment: That code is fairly easy, just override the same methods. If your doing the same thing, hiding all the controls when you rotate, then you should just do that and let the other elements grow appropriately as the custom full screen sample does that you pointed to. If you wish to post some of your code - layout and player - I can comment a bit more.

Comment: Updated the question. I added the layout and the player

Comment: Your layout doesn't include the player that your including in the rotation.

Comment: You can check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012754/android-youtube-api-v3-orientation

Answer (score 6):

by adding configChanges to you android manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".InfoActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

simply fix my problems:

- Starts buffering again
- Starts from the begining again

when screen was rotated.

Cheers.