# Android YouTube api v3 - orientation

Tags: android, api, youtube, orientation

Getting a sample activity up and running using YouTubeBaseActivity, YouTubePlayerView and YouTubePlayer was simple enough. I'm having trouble with orientation though and can't find any documentation or sample code. When I switch while a video is playing the screen is blank.

What are the correct things to do in each of onCreate(), onPause(), onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() to have the video continue playing?

Thanks

Comment: Figured it out myself - the mistake was I was not initializing the YouTubePlayerView in onCreate() when onCreate() was called during a restore rather than an explicit create. All fixed..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Variables

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
        ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
        ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE;

private YouTubePlayer mPlayer = null;
private boolean mAutoRotation = false;
```

OnCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAutoRotation = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1;
}
```

Implement OnInitializedListener

```
@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
        boolean wasRestored) {
    mPlayer = player;
    player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
    
    if (mAutoRotation) {
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
    } else {
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
    }
}
```

Inplement onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        if (mPlayer != null)
            mPlayer.setFullscreen(true);
    } 
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        if (mPlayer != null)
            mPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean fullsize) {
    if (fullsize) {
        setRequestedOrientation(LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION);
    } else {
        setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
    }
}
```

Menifest

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.sample.android.YouTubePlayerActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

I've made sample activity which uses most recent youtube api.

This source handle "**Orientation Problem**", "**Media Volume Problem**", "**Youtube Url Parsing Problem**"

1. Here is git project for sample app

   https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity
2. I also made sample app you can download

   https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.thefinestartist.ytpa.sample

Comment: Great answer and great library!

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here for others.  The Finest Artist's answer worked for me as well, but since I'm using a video player inside a fragment and have to support the AppCompatLibrary as well, here's what I was able to get working:

**YouTubePlayerActivityFragment.java**

```
public class YouTubePlayerActivityFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
        ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private static final int LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
        ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE;

private YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener fullScreenListener = null;
private YouTubePlayer yPlayer = null;
private boolean mAutoRotation = false;


public static YouTubePlayerActivityFragment newInstance(String videoID, String apiKey) {
    YouTubePlayerActivityFragment fragment = new YouTubePlayerActivityFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("video_id", videoID);
    bundle.putString("api_key", apiKey);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.init();
    return fragment;
}

public YouTubePlayerActivityFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
    super.onCreate(var1);
    mAutoRotation = Settings.System.getInt(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1;
    fullScreenListener = this;
}

private void init() {
    initialize(getArguments().getString("api_key"), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
            yPlayer = youTubePlayer;
            youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(fullScreenListener);
            if (mAutoRotation) {
                youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            } else {
                youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI
                        | YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            }

            if (!wasRestored) {
                yPlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("video_id"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullSize) {
    if (isFullSize) {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(LANDSCAPE_ORIENTATION);
    } else {
        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
    }
}
```