# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in a single-Activity app with orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, android-orientation, android-youtube-api

I tried to solve this problem, searched through the Internet, no real answer was found.

I'm developing an app where the YouTube player is needed. This player is the [`YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) since it's in a support fragment (so it's also nested). After the initial setup I realized that whenever I rotate the phone, the video stops playing and it has to be restarted again. This is obviously not what I want.

Then I found some SO answers ([*like this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32791655/2644098)) where people say that the Activity needs to handle the config changes, so I added `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to the Activity in the manifest. This solved the problem, the video now keeps playing even on orientation change and the full-screen rotation doesn't look ugly. Cool, I said, only to realize that this messed up big time the other parts of the app because the config is now being updated *after* all the views are in place. This means that if my phone was in portrait mode and I rotated it to landscape, the layout being used was still going to be the portrait one.

I found solutions for this suggesting calling `setContentView(...)` in the Activity's `onConfigurationChanged(...)` and reinflating the view in the Fragments, but this seems to be a rather cumbersome if not terrible solution as It's not just a simple content setting I need, the fragments need to be retained (e.g. scroll position in `RecyclerView`) too. The built-in `setRetainInstance(true)` does not work in this case as the view would be recreated with that either, but the config is still the old one when the `onCreateView(...)` is being called.

It would be nice if I could catch the `configChanges` events if the user is on that screen (fragment) only but retain Activity recreation anywhere else.

*Don't suggest using more Activities, I **cannot** use a separate Activity for this screen and the rest of the app because of UI/UX reasons.*

Comment: So if the player fragment is problematic then inflate that in separate activity and add properties to this activity.The rest will not be affected with these configs.

Comment: Like I said in the last sentence: using another Activity is **not an option**.

Comment: Did you try to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstance state that always used, when you want to keep some state through orientation changings? I don't know what structure of code do you have, but for example in onSaveInstanceState you can keep video id, that is playing right now and time. And in onRestoreInstanceState take this data and pass to fragment or YoutubePlayer or whatever. In this case no need in 'android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"'

Comment: This would not help because the main problem is not the availability of the current timestamp nor the video ID but the rebuffering and an ugly looking rotation effect that happens on orientation change.

Comment: Will this overview help ? http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Comment: @Stallion Not really, the parent fragment already retains its state. The problem is that the YouTube fragment catches the lifecycle events so it knows that there's a change happening, that's why the configuration change override would work because it is handled internally then.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) YouTube Android Player API Guidelines

> It is encouraged that you handle configuration changes caused by
>   orientation in your activity manually, to avoid recreating this
>   fragment's view every time the configuration changes. For the best
>   user experience, you should also manually handle the fullscreen event
>   by changing the layout of your activity.(See the second approch)

As you are already handling on configuration change on your own, I can see two possible solutions of your problem.

1. Set [setFullscreenControlFlags](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#setFullscreenControlFlags(int)) (To your `YouTubePlayer` object) to [`FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE) (This will causes the player to automatically enter fullscreen whenever the device enters landscape orientation.) in conjunction with [`FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION)(To enable automatic control of the orientation.) flag.

> Note that this flag should only be set if your activity is locked in
>   portrait (and is specified as such in the manifest).
>
> The flag is useful if you don't have a landscape layout for your
>   activity, but would like to enable landscape orientation solely for
>   fullscreen video watching.

2. This approach might solve your problem and it is also suggested by official documentation as I mentioned above. In `setFullscreenControlFlags` method set [`FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT), that disables the default fullscreen layout handler, enabling you to control the transition to fullscreen layout manually. As well as enabling you to implement a custom fullscreen layout, this option also provides the advantage of avoiding the rebuffering that occurs in the default fullscreen behavior.

> An application implementing custom fullscreen behavior should ensure
>   two things
>
> That the player's view takes up the whole available space of
>   application's window whenever onFullscreen(boolean) is called. That
>   the activity is not recreated when the orientation changes to
>   landscape. To achieve this for an activity that supports portrait, you
>   need to specify that your activity handles some configuration changes
>   on its own in your application's manifest, including orientation,
>   keyboardHidden and screenSize.

See [here](https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/blob/master/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo/FullscreenDemoActivity.java) on how to use this flag.

As per the first [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) I shared, this second approach will avoid recreating fragment's view every time the configuration changes. Also you don't need to call `setContentView(...)` in `onConfigurationChanged(...)`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but you probably misunderstood the problem. I don't currently handle the config changes on my own because it seems really difficult (like I constantly get exceptions everywhere if I try to call `setContentView(...)` again). If I set the flags in the `configChanges` attribute in the manifest, the player works in fullscreen and "windowed" mode too, but the views don't get the updated config, so if I have two layouts for portrait and landscape separately, the portrait will still be used in landscape, because the `onCreate(...)` happens with the old config.

Comment: @gergely can you paste your code if it possible. What I understand is your onConfigurationChanged(...) method didnt call though you are specifying configChanges attribute in manifest with value keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize, In case of orientation change your onCreate(...) method calls. Your expected behavior is onConfigurationChanged(...) method will be called when orientation change instead of onCreate(..). Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, if I specify the `configChanges` attribute, the YouTube video works fine even if the orientation changes, but the rest of the app gets messed up, because it will not load the valid resources (like I said, it's gonna load the portrait layout in landscape mode). If I don't specify the `configChanges`, then the rest of the app works (of course) but the YouTube video gets screwed since it stops and reloads on orientation change. I want to achieve that the rest of the app works fine while the YouTube fragment continues playing the video on orientation change.

Comment: Have you tried my first solution without specifying configChanges?

Comment: Didn't have time to test yet. Though I have to provide a portrait and a landscape mode too, the portrait also has to be available in non-fullscreen. I'll test it later though.

Comment: Also check the second approach and the example link of the same. Kindly Go through all the provided link if you didnt, it might clear your doubts.